# How to restart updates on Windows XP that were cancelled

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

I manually started a bunch of Windows updates that were due on my Windows XP machine (which is set to auto-download, but prompts me before installing). However, I needed to use my machine at the time, and the update was hogging too much resource. I therefore cancelled it, with a view to restarting the updates at a later time. However, I can't find a way of doing this - I don't want an insecure system, so want to do so ASAP.

The only thing I have tried is going to the Windows Update site with IE, but that seems to hang looking for updates to apply.

So, has my "cancelling" of the updates actually stopped the ability for me to ever apply them? If not, how do I restart them? They have downloaded to my machine, so I would have thought there would be a way to install them.

Comment: I assume you have tried to restart your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yes, a reboot was all I needed to do - my bad.

It does seem like a waste of time having to reboot twice - once to bring back the option of installing updates and one to do so after they're done.